# Facing permission error while deploying gke cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, rbac

I'm getting permission error while deploying into a GKe cluster

Error: when creating manifesting :cluster roles. rbac. Authorization. K8s. iris forbidden:user maxi2245@.com cannot create resource cluster roles in API group

I'm new to kubernetes and I try to learn few concepts in gke

I'm getting permission error while deploying ondat to a gke cluster I think due to  issue in roles

Help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#credential-rotation-node-recreate) The permission error messages returned are the result of not having the necessary privileges to install Ondat in a GKE cluster.

> To resolve this issue, ensure that your user account has cluster
> administrator privileges first so that you can install Ondat
> successfully.
>
> ```
> kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding \
>   --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
>   --user=$(gcloud config get-value account)
> ```
>
> Refer to this official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control) for more information about
> authorizing actions in clusters using role-based access control.